# Drop down menu. Sub menu drops down when you hover where it will appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Ideally, I want the drop down menu to only appear when the parent button is hovered / clicked.  However, the sub-menu is showing up when you hover over anywhere that the menu will appear.  I put it in JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7g67j/

Ideal outcome is the adjustment to the JS that would make it so that the drop downs appear ONLY when the button they are under is hovered...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var w = $(window).width();
if(w > windowWdth) {$('#block_navigation > ul').css('display', 'block');    $('#block_navigation').css('height', '55px');
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me... I tried Firefox, Chrome and IE and they all look good. What are you trying it on?

Comment: Chrome.  Maybe I didn't explain the issue very well.  If you hover anywhere where the drop down menu WILL BE, it shows up.  So for instance, under "Family Law" the last item on the menu is "protection from abuse" if you just mouse where the "Protection from Abuse" button would appear, the menu appears.  It should only appear when you mouse over "Family Law" at the top.   Does that make sense?

Comment: Whoa, that's weird. I see what you mean now :P

Comment: Well your problem is that the drop downs are always there, just with an opacity of 0. This (combined with all your hovers) means hovering over them makes them appear.  Most people use `display: block` and `display: none` for drop down menus (instead of changing the opacity). This kills your animation though http://jsfiddle.net/7g67j/4/

Comment: You could try messing with all your hover elements a bit more as well.

Answer (score -1):

here is your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g67j/1/). you have to add visibility:hidden in this div

```
#block_navigation ul ul {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Interesting... If this is what they are trying to do, this is some weird UI. I didn't understand this from the question though (which is kind of vague)

Comment: Well, that "Hidden" property is making it so that the menu does not show up above the slideshow beneath it...  Tried playing with Z-index, not able to get menu to show above element below...

Comment: On second thought, other element had Z-index as well.  I think we are all set here.   Thank you very much for your help.